Exporting function with Napi::Object return type by Napi::InstanceWrap<T>::InstanceMethod using node-addon-api
Preface:
I have a CPP class managing Napi::Buffer objects which use mmap(2)ed shared memory as external store which is based on provided example for Napi::ObjectWrap<T> found here; Here's the declaration:
class mmapIPC : public Napi::ObjectWrap<mmapIPC>
{
  public:
    static Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports);
    mmapIPC(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info);
    static Napi::Value CreateNewItem(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info);

  private:
    //-----------members
    shm_metadata shm_hint;
    Napi::Buffer<void> memoryBuffer;
    //-----------funcs
    Napi::Object buffer(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info);
    Napi::Value acquireReadLock(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info);
    //... various declarations omitted
};

Inside static Napi::Object Init() I export above members as follow:
// This method is used to hook the accessor and method callbacks
    Napi::Function functionList = DefineClass(env, "mmapIPC",
    {
        InstanceMethod<&mmapIPC::buffer>("buffer", static_cast<napi_property_attributes>(napi_writable | napi_configurable)),
        InstanceMethod<&mmapIPC::acquireReadLock>("acquireReadLock", static_cast<napi_property_attributes>(napi_writable | napi_configurable)),
        InstanceMethod<&mmapIPC::acquireWriteLock>("acquireWriteLock", static_cast<napi_property_attributes>(napi_writable | napi_configurable)),
        InstanceMethod<&mmapIPC::removeLock>("removeLock", static_cast<napi_property_attributes>(napi_writable | napi_configurable)),
        StaticMethod<&mmapIPC::CreateNewItem>("CreateNewItem", static_cast<napi_property_attributes>(napi_writable | napi_configurable))
    });

And finally, definition for Napi::Object buffer() is:
Napi::Object mmapIPC::buffer(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info)
{
    return this->memoryBuffer;
}

quite simple, acting as a getter (perhaps) to workaround question item #2 (see below).
Questions:

First and most important problem is, when buffer() returns Napi::Object (just like above code does), InstanceMethod<>() complains:
"no instance of overloaded function "mmapIPC::InstanceMethod" matches the argument list"
and using Napi::Value as return type, writing into the buffer using mmapIPC_obj.buffer().write('foo bar baz!', 'ascii') seems to work but mmapIPC_obj.buffer().toString('ascii') prints the whole stack trace and dumps the process!
I should note, exporting function with Napi::Object return type using Non-OOP style was working fine:

exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "buffer"), Napi::Function::New(env, buffer));


As memoryBuffer is a field, I tried to use Napi::InstanceWrap<T>::InstanceValue() but I couldn't seem to figure it out how it works (I'm pretty noob with CPP, and docs are really not that good). Shouldn't I use InstanceValue() instead of a function?
When initializing a new Napi::buffer as the code below, is it fine to supply void as the type? Compile process shows a warning about Napi tries to use sizeof void; Should I cast it to char* or u_int8_t* for example?

this->memoryBuffer =  Napi::Buffer<void>::New(
                        env,
                        returnedPointerFromMmap,
                        this->shm_hint.mmapLength,
                        freeCallback,
                        &this->shm_hint);


At the example provided for ObjectWrap there's this static Napi::Value CreateNewItem() method which retrieves the stored constructor and I quote:
"to create a new instance of the JS class the constructor represents".
What does this method do? Couldn't I just create another instance using the required constructor in my JS code? It says in the comments for static Napi::Object Init() that:
"allow this add-on to support multiple instances of itself running on multiple worker threads, as well as multiple instances of itself running in different contexts on the same thread"!
So is this method necessary? What does it do?


P.S: I apologize if this turned out to be a long question; I just wanted to ask it all once and get it over with; And also help whoever ends up here in search for an answer!
